# NGINX, proxy_pass and SPA routing in HTML5 mode

Tags: html, angular, nginx

I have NGINX set up as a reverse proxy for a virtual network of docker containers running itself as a container. One of these containers serves an Angular 4 based SPA with client-side routing in HTML5 mode.

The application is mapped to location / on NGINX, so that http://server/ brings you to the SPA home screen.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://spa-server/;
    }

    location /other/ {
        proxy_pass http://other/;
    }

    ...
}
```

The Angular router changes the URL to http://server/home or other routes when navigating within the SPA.

However, when I try to access these URLs directly, a 404 is returned. This error originates from the `spa-server`, because it obviously does not have any content for these routes.

The examples I found for configuring NGINX to support this scenario always assume that the SPA's static content is served directly from NGINX and thus `try_files` is a viable option.

How is it possible to forward any unknown URLs to the SPA so that it can handle them itself?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The solution that works for me is to add the directives `proxy_intercept_errors` and `error_page` to the `location /` in NGINX:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://spa-server/;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 404 = /index.html;
    }

    location /other/ {
        proxy_pass http://other/;
    }

    ...
}
```

Now, NGINX will return the /index.html i.e. the SPA from the `spa-server` whenever an unknown URL is requested. Still, the URL is available to Angular and the router will immediately resolve it within the SPA.

Of course, now the SPA is responsible for handling "real" 404s. Fortunately, this is not a problem and a good practice within the SPA anyway.

UPDATE: Thanks to @dan

Comment: This does indeed return the content of the index.html for 404s. But it also returns a 404 status code. I managed to fix this using `error_page 404 = /index.html` (note the `=`)

Comment: I had the same exact problem (though with an Elm SPA), and your answer along with Dan's comment helped a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have tried to implement this, but the error page is trying to be loaded from /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html rather than from the proxy_pass url.

Comment: It looks like this only works inside a location of / but mine needs to be something like: 
location /some-path/ {

Comment: Sussed it out, the error page also will need the path: e.g.
error_page 404 = /some-path/index.html;

Comment: @Martin Klinke This doesn't seem to be working for me. It redirects to the root of the SPA, but it truncates the url for the client so the SPA can't handle it.